# How to measure confidence in non-binary (e.g. ordinal) choice tasks?

Tags: measurement, methodology, metacognition, confidence

In metacognition literature, why is confidence, regardless of scale (Likert-type or continuous) and definition (e.g. decision confidence as a subjective probability of a decision being correct), mostly measured in binary decision tasks, such as 2AFC?

Is it psychologically valid to obtain confidence in other types of choice tasks, such as multiple-alternatives or ordinal ones, in a similar way?

Comment: Confidence gets complicated when you have more than two choices. If you have options ABCD you may be very confident it is either A or B but not actually certain that A is the correct answer. In this case you have a mixture of confidences at different levels of comparison. Two-alternative tasks are easier to analyze for many reasons and often multiple alternative tasks can be distilled to two choice tests anyways.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. It’s really an insightful example. But I’m still wondering if people are good at probabilities (Bayesian), an ordinary single-step way for measuring confidence (as probability of choice among ABCD being correct) and a hierarchical way, e.g. first, prob. of AB being correct (e.g. 90% for sure), and then prob of A being correct between A and B (e.g. 50% for sure) make a big difference: i.e. the former may directly yield 45 %, and the latter does 90% x 50% = 45%. It would be appreciated if you or someone else could cite some theories or previous studies if any. Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-binary choices complicate analysis unnecessarily, as most multiple alternative scenarios can be distilled into multiple binary choices.

Outside of metacognitive literature, I have seen studies that assume the naive Bayesian approach for multi-choice decision confidence, for example, from [Satopää et al (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2013.09.009) in forecasting:

> For now, assume that the event can take exactly one of a total of M≥2
> different outcomes. Under pure ignorance, the forecaster should assign
> a probability of 1/M to each outcome. The more ignorant the forecaster
> is, the more we would expect him to shrink his forecasts towards 1/M.

However, this assumption may not hold in the uncalibrated confidence judgments of metacognitive tasks.  There is an interesting paper by [Li & Ma (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-020-15581-6):

> Experiments on confidence reports have almost exclusively focused on
> two-alternative decision-making. ... Here, we test ... a
> three-alternative visual categorization task. We found that confidence
> reports are best explained by the difference between the posterior
> probabilities of the best and the next-best options, rather than by
> the posterior probability of the chosen (best) option alone, or by the
> overall uncertainty (entropy) of the posterior distribution. Our
> results upend the leading notion of decision confidence and instead
> suggest that confidence reflects the observer’s subjective probability
> that they made the best possible decision.

This would make even 4-choice tasks much more difficult to interpret.